# Alternative way of developing own Hardware

Tags: arduino, gps

Developing your own hardware is expensive. Our company has few requirements for our hardware. *Cellular communication, GPS transmission and capturing acceleration.*

Since we need only max to 1,000-5,000 devices the production costs is up to around $100 per device. So we thought of attaching cheap Xiaomi smartphone instead of it. (around $200)

But the best way to achieve this is using others hardware which as same functionality such as car GPS tracker, pet GPS tracker etc..

Wouldn't there be any Device I can use for this? With custom firmware, API, and hardware casing.

Comment: Hi uzu, unless you get a lot more specific there is really not a lot we can do for you. Even then hardware recommendations are not the core of what we do here. Have a look at [ask] and the please add the required information via [edit] to your question. Thank you.

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be possible. Your product design consultancy should offer this as a recommendation. There are always 3 possibilities to be explored in product design:

1. COTS (buy something that's already for sale).
2. Re-purpose something similar.
3. Design something custom.

In this case there are many companies that make tracker type devices that have white-labelling services. That is, they will allow you to buy their generic device and brand it/configure it however you like.

I strongly recommend you still do this through an electronic product design service (disclosure: I run such a service) - there are many competing trade-offs and specifications that need to be carefully worked through.

Comment: Heath, please comment on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10368/off-the-shelf-cheap-wearable-bluetooth-low-energy-device Thanks